# How to analyse the app store crash reports

Tags: codenameone

How to analyse the crash reports from App Store App analytics when I release a build using CN1. I see the online help if we release the App using XCode. Now, I only see number of crashes and at what date these crashes happen. Is there any process that should be included in the build to record the logs.Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Unless you used xcode to build the release these can't be decoded. xcode has its own obfuscation which we can't support. We made an attempt to support it in the past but it didn't work well.

We have a crash protection feature for pro developers which emails unobfuscated Java callstacks to you even in iOS crashes.

Comment: yes but email unobfuscated Java callstacks is doesn't give us the complete details to fix the issue. is there any other mechanism to identify better. Thanks

Comment: You would need to reproduce this in xcode or add additional logging to indicate it. The crash report would be too low level for most cases.